# Persistent Karma test runner with autoWatch=false

Tags: karma-runner

I am trying to run Karma via node (gulp, specifically) persistently in the background but to manually re-run the tests i.e. I have `autoWatch` set to `false`.  I start the server with something like:

```
karma_server = new karma.Server(config.karma)
karma_server.start()
```

Then elsewhere I would like to trigger the tests running when files are updated outside Karma. The [API method](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html) that one would expect might work is `server.refreshFiles()`, but it does not do this.

Internally it seems like [`executor.schedule()`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/server.js#L189) might do the trick, but it seems to be undocumented, private, and inaccessible.

So when `autoWatch` is turned off, how does one trigger Karma testing with an existing server?  I'm sure I must be missing something obvious as otherwise the `autoWatch` option would always need to be true for the server to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a server already running you can use the karma runner to communicate with it:

```
var runner = require('karma').runner,
    karmaConfig = {/* The karma config here */};

runner.run(karmaConfig, callback);
```

The grunt-karma plugin works like this, you can check it out for more info:
https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/blob/master/tasks/grunt-karma.js